# Serving an image with Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

I have a GET service who should serve an image. Following the Grape readme:
https://github.com/intridea/grape#user-content-sending-raw-or-no-data

```
get :image do
  content_type 'application/octet-stream'
  File.binread "image.png"
end
```

But when I download the image is missing its extension (.png) and the filename.

I have tried too:

```
get :image do
  content_type 'image/png'
  File.binread "image.png"
end
```

But it returns the error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)
```

How should send the image for avoiding to lose extension and filename?

Comment: HI, Have you solved the problem? I meet too.

Answer (score 0):

You cando like this, Add `content_type :png, "image/png"` before it.

```
content_type :png, "image/png"
get :image do
  content_type 'image/png'
  File.binread "image.png"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might run into this in the future, the correct solution is adding a line for the header property, like so:

```
header['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=filename.png"
```

"attachment" can be switched to "inline" if you want the file displayed on the browser.